Indistinguishable Security and Message Recovery
Let $\pi$ be an encryption scheme that is indistinguishable secure. That is the probability of an adversary winning the game is $\leq \frac{1}{2} + negl(n)$.
How can I use proof by reduction to show that if $\pi$ is indistinguishable secure (IND-secure) then it is message recovery secure?
In the message recovery game, the adversary has to guess the message $m$ given the ciphertext $c$. What will be the success probability of adversary $A$ trying to attack the IND-security game using adversary $A'$ breaking message recovery?

Hint: As stated otherwise, the question asks how you can use an attack against message recovery to help distinguish an attack. Use an MR attacker to build an IND attacker. While working through the details, analyze how the IND attacker probability relates to that of the MR attacker. Also, you might need to make the definitions a bit more precise.
